# What are my react project files not opening in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal

The path I followed was download project files from qualified -> unzip -> npx create-react-app appname -> cd appname -> npm start -> code .

The project is opened in browser on the default page, but code . is not doing anything.  Terminal is reading "Compiled successfully!

You can now view react-router-assessment in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3002
On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.9:3002

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
code .
code .
code .
code ."

When i enter vscode to open the files from there, they aren't showing among the files on my computer.

See the preceding post